# Gradle - Package Project to be used as dependency

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Spring project using Gradle that I want to package and upload to a maven repository to be used as a dependency in other Gradle projects. I tried using the `maven-publish` plugin to do this but the generated JAR has two issues - 
1. it is generating a fat jar.
2. there is no pom.xml or any other file in jar that would tell the consumer project about the project's dependencies.

How can I accomplish the two tasks?

Comment: If your project is a spring boot application, then it shouldn't be used as a dependency. Make it two modules: one which actually is the library you want to be used as a dependency, and one which is the Spring boot application.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the advice. I'll fix that. Can you still explain how to build project to be used as dependency?

Comment: Once you have a module that is a plain old Java project, which doesn't use the spring-boot plugin which, I guess, makes your jar a fat jar, you just follow the gradle guide.

Comment: @JBNizet actually, if you read the question, making a fat jar is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I understood that. That's why I told you to extract the classes that should consist in a separate library in a separate module, **not** using the spring-boot plugin, and thus **not** generating a fat jar, and which will thus generate a plain old Java library, using the java plugin, that can be published using the publish plugin, and that can be used as a dependency like any other library.

Comment: Can I not instead have the jar contain a pom.xml and let the consuming project download required dependencies?